# Why is url not registered?(Drupal 6.x)

Tags: url, drupal

I'm using hook_menu to register new url so that accessing this url would return some data to ajax function. As title suggested, this url is not registered. How do I know that? I've tried typing this in address bar but, drupal, return main template only rather than the tests string that I created. I'm positive that my module is working for php issues error if I intentionally write wrong syntax. And, yes, I clear cache whenever I make changes. Here's the code -

```
function test_menu() {
$my_form['test'] = array(
    'title' => 'Test address',
    'page callback' => 'test',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

return $my_form;
```

}

function test(){
        $a= "testing";

```
return $a;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal is returning the variable, but your code isn't exposing it. To see it, add the following line to the `test()` function before the `return` line:

```
drupal_set_message('Variable $a: ' . $a);
```

This will display the text and the variable value in the content area of the page, so that you know that Drupal is registering the path (and is running the `test()` function and can use its variables):

```
Variable $a: testing
```

If `$a` is an array, this will not display it's value, but only the type of the variable ('Array'). To see the elements of this array:

```
$a = array ('testing', 'element2', 'item3');
```

Use the PHP `print_r()` function to print an indented list of the array's elements. Enclose it in HTML `pre` tags to have the indentation line up nicely:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>Array $a: ' . print_r($a). '</pre>');
```

This will output the array in this format:

```
Array
(
    [0] => testing
    [1] => element2
    [2] => item3
)
```

Comment: I thought just returning the value that I wanted to use, would do the trick. Drupal works otherwise. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No problem. The test_menu() function returns a variable, but that's OK because the function that is building the menus and paths WANTS a variable back. But when the test() function runs (when someone goes to that path), Drupal is assembling the page and is looking for HTML to be returned.